# Trying to extract Goutte data to view

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler, goutte

I have been working for hours trying to figure out how to extract some data to my view in Laravel.

my controller is as follows:

```
  public function practice(Request $request) 
    {

        $client = new Client();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.polkadotpassport.com/');

$crawler->filter('.post-header')->each(function($node){
   $title = $node->filter('h2 > a');
    return view('flights', compact('title'));
});


    }
```

and then my view is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

@foreach($title as $titles)
<h1>{{$titles}}</h1>
@endforeach


@endsection
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Give us some information on your problem. What data are you trying to extract? What error are you getting (or what is not working as you expect it to)?  And why do you have your `return view(..)` statement within an `each` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `crawler` is returning a collection, try something like:

```
public function practice(Request $request)
{
        $client = new Client();
        $crawler = $client->request(
                'GET',
                'https://www.polkadotpassport.com/
        ');

        $titles = $crawler->filter('.post-header')->map(function($node){
                return $node->filter('h2 > a');
        });

        return view('flights', ['titles' => $titles]);
}
```